# Unable to compile cpp via docker in Travis-CI: /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am using a very simple .travis.yml to compile a cpp program via docker in Travis-CI. (My motivation is to experiment running docker in Travis CI.)

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

before_install:
- docker pull glot/clang

script:
  - sudo docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/app -w /app glot/clang g++ main.cpp
```

But the [build is failing](https://travis-ci.org/maddyonline/running-docker-in-ci/builds/99199113) with following error:
`/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied`. This is regardless of whether I use `sudo` or not. Can someone help me out figuring out the root cause and help fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to set mounting path explicitly rather then doing it with `$(pwd)`. Then you need to check the permissions from inside the container. Try something like that:

```
sudo docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/app -w /app glot/clang stat /app
```

This will show folder permissions. Probably noone is able to write into this folder.

Also you should avoid building your software using `root` permissions, it's not secure. Create non-priveleged user and use them when you running the compiler.

**UPD:**
I cannot reproduce this issue with `docker 1.6.0`, probably it's caused by some filesystem settings persisted by Travis-CI virtual machine. This is what I have on my localhost:

```
➜  /tmp  mkdir /tmp/code
➜  /tmp  echo "int main(){}" > /tmp/code/main.cpp
➜  /tmp  echo "g++ main.cpp && ls -l" > /tmp/code/build.sh
➜  /tmp  docker run --rm -v /tmp/code:/app -w /app glot/clang bash /app/build.sh  
total 20
-rwxr-xr-x 1 glot glot 8462 Dec 30 10:19 a.out
-rwxrwxr-x 1 glot glot   22 Dec 30 10:17 build.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 glot glot   13 Dec 30 10:10 main.cpp
```

As you see, the resulting binary appears in `/app` folder

Comment: `Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1001/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: ( 1001/ UNKNOWN)` This is what I see: https://travis-ci.org/maddyonline/running-docker-in-ci/builds/99354259. Do you have any recommendation how to get past this? Thanks.

Comment: @MadhavJha sorry but I can't reproduce it on my host, I've updated my post. You need to know what exactly prevents ```ld``` from creating a file there. ```strace``` would be usefull here because it traces all system call and error but I'm not sure if it will work in Docker (probably ```--priviliged``` will help)